# Jquery - Show / Hide Textarea when a href is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have an a href and a textarea, I used link because the button is not fit in my design. The problem is I want to Show the textarea when the tag `<a>` is clicked and change the text from "Reply (show)" to "Reply (hide)" my code isn't working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#replyshow").click(function(){
    var rep = $("#replyshow").text();
    event.preventDefault();
    if (rep == "Reply (show)") {
        $("#reply").show(500);
        rep = $("#replyshow").text("Reply (hide)");
    } else {
        $("#reply").hide(500);
        rep = $("#replyshow").text("Reply (show)");
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is working... https://jsfiddle.net/mo8e565z/

Comment: you need to use event like this . function(event) { }

Comment: if it is not working on your end then check console if there is any error

Comment: Ok, I will check it. I saw the jsfiddle and it is working. Tnx btw.

Comment: On a side note, I would change your if statement to check whether `#reply` is visible, rather than the text content of `#replyshow`. Purely because the text content is not a boolean value. Something like `$("#reply").is(":visible")` should do it.

Comment: By the way, there are many #replyshow and #reply because it is looped. Is it the reason why it isn't working?

Comment: You can't use the id selector with multiple elements. Selectors by ID only return the 1st elements in the DOM.

Comment: I see so, that's why it isn't working. How to distinguish every elements?

Comment: You need to use some other selector that returns more than one object. Adding classed would probably be the easiest solution. Then you will have the task of targeting the right text area so you will need to use something to find the correct textarea out of all of the text areas you want to target.

Comment: Looks at the jQuery documentation for selectors and tree traversal https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ & https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: Here is a sample with multiple items with the correct targeting. https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/ztmkrqxo/

Comment: Also in the future share your html. We would have been able to determine you had multiple elements with the same ID to provide direction to take another route.

Comment: Okay. Thank you Sean. You're a big help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing event in `click` function call as @Jagadeesh commented. Your code should look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#replyshow").click(function(event){ // event is added here!
    var rep = $("#replyshow").text();
    event.preventDefault();
    if (rep == "Reply (show)") {
     $("#reply").show(500);
     rep = $("#replyshow").text("Reply (hide)");
    } else {
     $("#reply").hide(500);
     rep = $("#replyshow").text("Reply (show)");
    }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="replyshow">Reply (hide)</a>

<textarea id="reply"></textarea>
```

Comment: I know what my error now. I had many #replyshow and #reply because it is looped. Thanks anyway.